# What are the "big operators" for logical operations?

Tags: logic, notation

Just like $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ are the "big operators" for summation and multiplication, what would such operators be for logical operations? For example, would $\bigwedge\limits_{i} b_i$ be the logical-and operator applied on the set of booleans $b_i$? For some reason, although LaTeX does have `\sum`, there does not seem to exist any `\And` or `\Or`.

Comment: There is `\bigvee` $\bigvee$ and `\bigwedge` $\bigwedge$ – is this a mathematical question or a question about LaTeX?

Comment: @MartinR It's a mathematical question, but since I'll eventually need to write down what I'm talking about, I'd naturally like to also know how to do so in LaTeX.

Comment: Your guesses about the meanings of $\bigwedge_i,\,\bigvee_i$ are correct, but note that if $\bot,\,\top$ are respectively labelled $0,\,1$ then $\bigwedge$ is equivalent to $\prod$.

Answer (score -1):

In first order logic "operators" are predicates.

you may have a formula:
$(\forall x)(\exists y)(xPy)$

$P$ is a predicate and $x,y$ are the bound variables.

a predicate can be $n-$ary which can be interpreted in a suitable domain of discourse.

In the example above $P$ is a binary predicate,  i.e. it acts on two variables.

Comment: So you mean the and operator $\land$ can't possibly by applied to a set (or more than two operands)? How does one represent an "and" operation on more than two booleans?

Comment: The $\land$ is not an operator, it is a connective.